# Wire SwiftUI Interaction among Components

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to wire up two components:

```
@State private var buttonState = ButtonState.DISABLED
@State private var emailAddressChangedValue = ""

VStack {
    TextEdit(editText: $viewModel.email, changedValue: $emailAddressChangedValue, placeholder: NSLocalizedString("onboarding.forgotpassword.email.label", comment: ""), keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.emailAddress)
            .padding(.top, 4)

    Button(action: {
        viewModel.sendPasswordResetRequest()
    }, label: {
            Text(NSLocalizedString("onboarding.forgotpassword.sendemail.label", comment:""))
            .padding()
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    })
    .buttonStyle(FooButtonStyle(buttonState: $buttonState))
    .disabled(!validateEmail(emailAddress: emailAddressChangedValue))
    .padding(.top, 8)
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
}
```

So, a person enters their email address and as they type, the `emailAddressChangedValue` emits the typed text. The email address is validated through `validateEmail(emailAddress: emailAddressChangedValue)` and once a valid email address occurs, the button becomes enabled.  However, I cannot figure out how to change the `$buttonState` which changes the color style from disabled to enabled.  I tried putting it within the `validateEmail` function but when I do that, I receive an error `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.`

So, how do I update `buttonState` within the VStack?

Comment: Can you show enough for a [mre]? Or at the least, include `validateEamil` and your `@State` variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `TextEdit` is like `TextField` or `TextEditor`, you could try adding `.onReceive{}`, like the following example code, to "...update buttonState within the VStack." (note, you need to `import Combine`):

```
VStack {
    TextEdit(editText: $viewModel.email, changedValue: $emailAddressChangedValue, placeholder: NSLocalizedString("onboarding.forgotpassword.email.label", comment: ""), keyboardType: UIKeyboardType.emailAddress)
        .padding(.top, 4)
    
    Button(action: {
        viewModel.sendPasswordResetRequest()
    }, label: {
        Text(NSLocalizedString("onboarding.forgotpassword.sendemail.label", comment:""))
            .padding()
            .font(.headline)
            .foregroundColor(Color.red)
    })
    // -- here --
    .onReceive(Just(emailAddressChangedValue)) { val in
       buttonState = !validateEmail(emailAddress: val)
    }
    .buttonStyle(FooButtonStyle(buttonState: $buttonState))
    .disabled(buttonState) // <-- could also be here 
    .padding(.top, 8)
    .padding(.horizontal, 8)
}
```